# jQuery validation not working with Chrome or IE8

Tags: jquery, validation, internet-explorer-8, jquery-validate

I am trying to use jQuery validation, and it does not validate upon submit. If I remove the rules, and add required to the firstName field, it will work under Chrome, but not IE8. As it sits, it won't work under either Chrome or IE8. I know IE8 has its quirks, but unfortunately my client REQUIRES IE8, but I am apparently missing something. Any advice?

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Validation Test</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){        
    $("#main_form").validate({
        rules: {
            firstName: {
                required: true
            }
        }
    })
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="main_form">
        <div>
            <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="firstName">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastName">
        </div>
        <div>
           <label for="address1">Address 1</label>
            <input type="text" id="address1">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="address2">Address 2</label>
            <input type="text" id="address2">
        </div> 
        <div>
            <label for="cityState">City/State</label>
            <input type="text" id="cityState">
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">Search</button>    
        </div>          
     </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all, please wrap that code in a `jQuery(function($) { // code in here });`. Some browsers buffer the output before parsing it, some don't. If it doesn't then your code executed before your form even exists in the DOM

Comment: Next, how are you testing IE8? Using "emulators" is usually unreliable, and the best way is to use a full-blown virtual machine with IE in it, see http://modern.ie/en-us. (I am assuming that you do not have IE8 installed as your default IE version).

Comment: I have IE8 installed as my default browser. As i said, my client REQUIRES IE8. But, the code above doesn't work in Chrome either.

Comment: I edited the code to wrap it in a jQuery function($) (see above) Same results ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info) for the jquery-validate tag.

> Rules are defined by input name attributes, not by id, when declared
>   within the rules option of validate().

So you need to add `name` attributes to each of your input fields, like so:

```
 <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName">
```